# Lossless compression theory, is compression ratio based on size of pattern and times repeated?

Tags: compression, binary-data, huffman-code, lzw, lossless

I was wondering which of the following scenarios will achieve the highest ratio with lossless algorithms applied to binary data with repeated data.

Am I correct to assume the compression ratio depends on patterns?

1. Size
2. Times repeated

For example the binary data:

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 pattern (10) size 2, pattern (10) repeated 8

1001 1001 1001 1001 pattern (1001) size 4, pattern (1001) repeated 4

0000000 11111111 pattern (0) size 1, pattern (0) repeated 8; pattern (1) size 1, pattern (1) repeated 8;
Or 
0000000 11111111 pattern (0000000) size 8, pattern (0000000) repeated 8; pattern (11111111) size 8, pattern (11111111) repeated 1;

Which of the above achieves the highest and lowest compression ratios?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first two examples should compress in the same way, if the algorithm is smart.  (They are equivalent -- the first one could also be viewed as being a pattern of size 4 and repeated 4 times.)  More generally, any pattern that is N length and repeats M times can be viewed as a pattern that is N*C length and repeats M/C times, for some constant C.

Comment: Compression algorithms are very different. There must be dozens of LZ-style algorithms. Why are you asking?

Comment: Hi all! Thank you for your responses. The reason why I asked is because I have an idea for an algorithm layer to apply before the lossless compression. This is all just concept, rigorous testing is yet to be done not to mention a prototype. I was curious as to the inputs to LZW and huffman lossless algorithm to ensure max compression. I have a flowchart of how I would like to apply the algorithm and its limits below: i46.tinypic.com/351vmll.png Your honest opinions? Feel free to poke holes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are all sequences that would be very unlikely to be seen in the wild.  What is the point of the question?

Run-of-the-mill compressors are byte-oriented.  As such, any pattern that results in simply the same byte repeated will give the highest compression ratio.  E.g. 1032:1 in the limit for deflate.  Other simple repetitions of short patterns will get very high compression ratios.  E.g. again 1032:1 for deflate for patterns of two or three repeating bytes.

The limit on compression in these absurdly extreme cases is a function of the compression format, not of the data.

Comment: Hi all!
Thank you for your responses.
The reason why I asked is because I have an idea for an algorithm layer to apply before the lossless compression. This is all just concept, rigorous testing is yet to be done not to mention a prototype. 
I was curious as to the inputs to LZW and huffman lossless algorithm to ensure max compression.
I have a flowchart of how I would like to apply the algorithm and its limits below:
http://i46.tinypic.com/351vmll.png

Your honest opinions? 
Feel free to poke holes.

Comment: You have some research to do.  LZW is obsolete, and Huffman coding is only part of other schemes to model redundancy.  Read about LZ77, the Burrows-Wheeler transform, prediction by partial matching, and arithmetic coding.  You can also take a look at XML-WRT which is a text preprocessor applied to improve subsequent lossless compression.